# Unique slugs to user

Tags: python, slug

Using the Python Library [Awesome-Slugify](https://github.com/dimka665/awesome-slugify) I am creating slugs like so:

```
unique_slug = UniqueSlugify()

text = 'This is Some Text'
slug = unique_slug(text) # Prints 'this-is-some-text'
```

The value of slug gets added to a database after it's created. If I want to create another slug with the same value it would look be `this-is-some-text-1`.

As my application lets users create slugs, if one user was to create a slug with the value `Some Text` it would be `some-text`. But if another user was to create a slug with the same value it would be `some-text-1`. If many users have the same value then the number would just increase and increase.

I would like the slugs to be unique to the user:

- User A creates a slug `unique_slug('hello world') # 'hello-world'`
- User B creates a slug `unique_slug('hello world') # 'hello-world'`
- User B creates another slug `unique_slug('hello world') # 'hello-world-1'`
- User C creates a slug `unique_slug('hello world') # 'hello-world'`

As you see I would like the slug to be unique to that user. It doesn't matter if different users share the same slug but a user cannot have the same ones.

How would I go about it preferably using Awesome-Slugify or another slug creation Python library? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the docs on the page you linked? The example under "Custom Unique Slugify Checker" appears to be what you need.

Comment: @Blorgbeard How would I go about implementing this for my issue?

Comment: Implement a `unique_check` function that connects to your database and checks whether the slug has been used for the user. I guess you'll need a `UniqueSlugify` instance per user.